# How to get employee id using excel sheet

Tags: python, django, excel, django-views, django-templates

I have created a system (in Django) where whenever I upload an excel file to the website, it will be loaded into the database.

How do I retrieve the EmpID from the DB and show it in HTML ?

[image: The excel sheet in the database]

**This is my views.py**

```
def upload_file_view(request):
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        form = EmployeeForm()
        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            
            next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
                EmpID = row[1].upper()
                EmpName = row[2].upper()
                EmpEmail = row[3].upper()
                Employee.objects.create(
                    EmpID = EmpID,
                    EmpName = EmpName,
                    EmpEmail = EmpEmail,
                )

            obj.activated = True
            obj.save()
            
    return render(request, "EmpDBUpload/upload.html", {'form':form})
```

**This is my Viewclaim.html**

```
 <h1> Emp id: {{EmpID}} </h1>
```

**This is my views.py for ViewClaim**

```
def ViewClaim(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  claims = Claims.objects.all()
  
  emp_ids = Employee.objects.values('EmpID')
  context = {'emp_ids': emp_ids}

  return render(request, 'User/ViewClaim.html', {'date': x, 'user':user, 'claims':claims} ,context=context)
```

Comment: You want to retrieve EmpID from Excel or from DB ?

Comment: Whichever tht is able to display

Comment: Retrieve it from DB as you have the data already in the DB. Write a query to fetch the EmpID in your view.

Comment: How do I write the query to retrieve into the html?

Comment: Please post the code of view (where you are sending the EmpID to html) for me to help you out.

Comment: I have added the codes below

Comment: Please post your ```view``` associated with ```Viewclaim.html```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You have posted the view (that serves ```EmpDBUpload/upload.html```). But I need the code of the view (that serves ```Viewclaim.html```). The code in my answer should be in this ```view```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ViewClaim`,

```
def ViewClaim(request): 
    context = initialize_context(request) 
    user = context['user'] 
    claims = Claims.objects.all()
    # Fetches the employee ids of all Employees
    emp_ids = Employee.objects.all() 
    
    return render(request, 'User/ViewClaim.html', {'date': x, 'user':user, 'claims':claims, 'emp_ids': emp_ids})
```

In your **Viewclaim.html**

```
{% for emp in emp_ids %}
    <h1> Emp id: {{ emp.EmpID }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError at /upload 
<br> render() got multiple values for argument 'context'

Comment: Did you add this code to ```upload_file_view``` view ?

Comment: Yes I added the  emp_ids at upload_file_view  and for loop at html

Comment: I clearly mentioned that you have to add this code to the view that serves Viewclaim.html and not to ```upload_file_view```.  How are you sending data to ```Viewclaim.html``` ? What is that view ?

Comment: I think you got mix up. The upload_file_view is linked to upload.html but I want it to display on Viewclaim.html as it is a separate project

Comment: I think you are new to Django. As in the question, you have mentioned the view - ```upload_file_view``` which serves the template ```upload.html```. Similarly there will be a view (X) which serves the template ```Viewclaim.html```. Kindly add that view - X to your question (or) Add this code to that view.

Comment: Let me try adding your code to the Viewclaim.html view first

Comment: This is my function for Viewclaim
def ViewClaim(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  claims = Claims.objects.all()
  
  emp_ids = Employee.objects.values('EmpID')
  context = {'emp_ids': emp_ids}

  return render(request, 'User/ViewClaim.html', {'date': x, 'user':user, 'claims':claims} ,context=context)

Comment: @EltonTan Please add this view to the question and remove those migrations (those are unnecessary) from the question.

Comment: Added the Viewclaim function

Comment: I am getting this: Could not parse the remainder: '['EmpID']' from 'emp['EmpID']'

Comment: Yes after I change my other code arrangement and added yours, I can finally display the Emp ID ! ! !

Comment: @EltonTan Glad to hear that! Please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: I can only accept your answer, couldnt up vote

Comment: How do I filter out that the employer id will only show based on the logged user of Azure 
@Ram?