# Getting EMPID to display in html using django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the value of the EmployeeID in views.py to display on an HTML page, ViewClaims.html.

In my views.py, I have used an excel sheet that links to the database. Please refer to [How to get employee id using excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403818/how-to-get-employee-id-using-excel-sheet)

**This is my views.py**

```
# Create your views here.  
def upload_file_view(request):
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        form = EmployeeForm()
        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            
            next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
                EmpID = row[1].upper()
                EmpName = row[2].upper()
                EmpEmail = row[3].upper()
                Employee.objects.create(
                    EmpID = EmpID,
                    EmpName = EmpName,
                    EmpEmail = EmpEmail,
                )

            obj.activated = True
            obj.save()
            
    return render(request, "EmpDBUpload/upload.html", {'form':form})
```

**ViewClaims.html**

```
 <h1>Transaction no.: {{  EmpID }} </h1>
```

I am trying to call the EMPID to display on the ViewClaims.html but I am not able to.

Comment: What happens when you try to call the EMPID on the ViewClaims?  Does it produce an error, or?

Comment: The code you quote doesn't render the ViewClaims.html template, so we can't see what variables are being passed to the template, or how you're actually using it. If you want to use a "EmpID" variable in a template, you need to pass that in to the template. I see it in your other question - where there are already lots of comments about this same matter.

Comment: Answers to my qns 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403818/how-to-get-employee-id-using-excel-sheet/68404794?noredirect=1#comment120894425_68404794